# SequelizeJS: Best way to get min ID and max ID in a table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

What is the Best way to get min ID and max ID in a table in SequelizeJS?

Now my code:

```
db.Message.max('id')
.then(max => {
  db.Message.min('id')
  .then(min => {
    resolve({ 'minId': max, 'maxID': min })
   })
})
```

Is this the best way? Please give your opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Sequelize that is the most straightforward and clear way to do fetch the `min` and `max`. If they are indexed properly the performance should be reasonable.

In the example you have the min and max variable assigned to the wrong key in the Promise resolution, it's backwards. You could also consider using the `async/await` style if your version of Node supports it.

```js
const max = await db.Message.max('id');
const min = await db.Message.min('id');
const minAndMax = { 'minId': min, 'maxID': max };
```